# Can not use substr function in MySQL to get left part of the string using last occurrence of delimiter

Tags: mysql

I have a question to worm up your minds :)

I need to extract a string A from string B where B is stored in MySQL table.

This is string B:

```
#/schema#/CT[Items]#/sequence[0]#/element[item]#/CT[]#/sequence[0]#/element[productImage]
```

And this is A:

```
#/schema#/CT[Items]#/sequence[0]#/element[item]#/CT[]#/sequence[0]
```

The delimiter in my case is '#' and I need to remove it along with the following characters `'/element[productImage]'`.

I tried different functions like `SUBSTR(str, pos, len)`, `POSITION(substr IN str)`, and `REVERSE(str)` but cannot solve the problem.

Note that index of the last occurrence of '#' is unknown. And I can not find a way to locate the last index of the '#' character (like lastIndexOf() function in JAVA).

I believe that there is a way to do it by reversing the whole string first, cutting the unnecessary part then reversing again to get the desired result.

Can any one help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
LEFT(str, CHAR_LENGTH(str) - LOCATE('#', REVERSE(str)))
```

Comment: nice idea, it looks much cleaner than my solution, +1

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of occurrences with:

```
CHAR_LENGTH(stringB)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(stringB, '#', ''))
```

and then you can just use SUBSTRING_INDEX:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    stringB,
    '#',
    CHAR_LENGTH(stringB)-CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(stringB, '#', '')))
```

Comment: Thanks fthiella for the suggest. I also tried your solution and works great.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it works

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING CONCAT("#", SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, '#', -1)) FROM str)
```

This part :

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, '#', -1)
```

grabs everything after the last token occurrence *without* the token

this bit :

```
TRIM(TRAILING 'x' FROM str)
```

returns the string with the last occurrence of 'x' (or whatever string provided) from the target string.

But since SUBSTRING_INDEX returns the substring without the delimiter token, you need to trim off the trailing token as well, for which we use the CONCAT to add it back to the front of the "bad" sub-string.

Comment: Seems like there are many solutions and all are correct. I compare the speed of each solution they are about 0.0003 sec which is rarely important.